# Trouble downloading wxpthon

Tags: terminal, wxpython, osx-lion

I'm very new to Python and using the terminal, and I'm having a lot of trouble downloading wxpython. I'm using Mac OS X Lion, the most recent version, and I've tried two methods:

If I try to simply download wxpython off their website, I go through the entire installation process and it says it's been installed but then I can't find it on my computer. And when I go to run the separately installed demo, it says that there's no module named wxpython on my computer. 
So I turned to other methods...

If I try sudo pip install wxpython, I get:

```
    Downloading/unpacking wxpython
      Downloading wxPython2.8-win64-devel-2.8.12.1-msvc9x64.tar.bz2 (7.2Mb): 7.2Mb downloaded
      Running setup.py egg_info for package wxpython
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
        IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michelletyler1/build/wxpython/setup.py'
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):

       File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michelletyler1/build/wxpython/setup.py'
```

I also tried sudo port install py27-wxpython after installing MacPorts, and got:

```
    --->  Computing dependencies for py27-wxpython
    --->  Building py27-wxpython
    Error: org.macports.build for port py27-wxpython returned: command execution failed
    Please see the log file for port py27-wxpython for details:
        /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-wxpython/py27-wxpython/main.log
    To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
        http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
    Error: Processing of port py27-wxpython failed
```

What can be wrong?

Also, I've been trying to figure out how to change my $PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin (as advised by brew doctor), but when I go to edit my ~/.profile (what I've gathered I'm supposed to do from what I've found online so far), it doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you don't want to install wxPython against the preinstalled Python. Instead, you need to go to www.python.org and install a fresh Mac compatible Python. Then you can download the wxPython you want and install it against your fresh Python. By the way, wxPython does not support easy_install or pip.